# after import csv file, redirects to http://localhost/index.php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, csv, import

Ok, I've made a page to import my stock file, which is in a `.csv` file (which works fine), but after the import is made, the page goes directly to my `localhost/index.php` instead of returning the "ok" message... why is that?

here's the code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Importar archivo</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
    <p class="help-block">Solo archivos .csv</p>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import"         value="Import">Importar</button>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick=" location.href='http://localhost/inicio.html'     " value="Inicio" name="boton" /> 
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["Import"]))
{
//me conecto a la BD
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Problemas en la conexion");
mysql_select_db("kontor",$conexion) or die("Problemas en la seleccion de la base de datos");

echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
{
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    $count = 0; 
    while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ";", '"')) !== FALSE)
    {
        $count++; 
        if($count>1){  
        mysql_query("INSERT into stock (SKU,nombre,descr,prbruto,prneto,fechaing,cantcentral,cantarauco,cantdrug,canttrebol) values ('$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]','$emapData[3]','$emapData[4]','$emapData[5]','$emapData[6]','$emapData[7]','$emapData[8]','$emapData[9]')", $conexion) or die("Problemas en el select: ".mysql_error());

        }       
    }
    fclose($file);
    echo 'Archivo importado';
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else
    echo 'Formato de archivo incorrecto';
}
?>
```

Comment: you are using: `header('Location: index.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `header('Location: index.php');` from your code.

That is causing the redirection.